# Using v-cloak not working on asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use the v-cloak directive to display a loading spinner as certain vue js data properties are loading asynchronously so I can feed it to a table component.

I have my v-cloak styles set and working properly when I apply them on the entire vue instance `<div id="app"></div>` element. However, the desired behavior is while mounting components, if the expected data i.e. an array of contacts is loading asynchronously from the server, I'd like to apply the v-cloak directive to the MyTable component which is waiting on the contacts to populate and rather than show an empty table, show a loading indicator.

Is this possible? if so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a misunderstanding of what `v-cloak` does.

#### [`v-cloak`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak)

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue instance finishes compilation.

if you want to hide something while something is loading, you need to manage the state and the loader yourself.

Usually this is done with something like a `computed` that is updated once data is loaded, which toggles the `loader` component for the other components using `v-if` or `v-show`

here is a simplified example...

```html
<template>
  <MySpinner v-if="loading"/>
  <MyTable v-else :data="myAsynchData"/>
<template>

<script>
//... some code here
  computed: {
    loading => this.myAsynchData == undefined
  }
//... more code
</script>
```